# JQuery .on event not firing

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap, events, thymeleaf

I have an jquery on event in order to pass some data into a bootstrap modal window. Here's the code from the modal:

```
<div class="modal fade" id="renameFile" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="renameFile" aria-hidden="true">
<div class="modal-dialog">
    <div class="modal-content">
        <div class="modal-header">
            <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal"><span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span><span class="sr-only">close</span></button>
            <h4 class="modal-title" id="formRenameTitle">rename</h4>
        </div>
        <div class="modal-body">
            <form method="post" th:action="files">
                <div class="input-group">
                    <input type="text" class="form-control" id="fileName" name="fileName" />
                    <span class="input-group-btn">
                        <button class="btn btn-default" type="submit">rename</button>
                    </span>
                </div>
                <input type="hidden" name="action" value="EDIT" />
                <input type="hidden" name="fileId" />
            </form>
        </div>
        <div class="modal-footer">
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">close</button>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
</div>
```

and here's the code for the button (it normally lives in the cell of a grid):

```
<a data-toggle="modal" data-id="${{file.id}}" data-name="${{file.name}}" title="rename" class="open-renameFile" href="#renameFile">
    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-pencil" aria-hidden="true</span>rename
</a>
```

I'm using thymeleaf to populate the cells of each row.

And at the bottom of the page I've included this javascript:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).on("click", ".open-renameFile", function () {
    var fileName = $(this).data('name');
    $(".modal-body #fileName").val( fileName );
});
$(document).on("click", ".open-renameFile", function () {
    var fileId = $(this).data('id');
    $(".modal-body #fileId").val( fileId );
});     
</script>
```

Comment: How do you know the events are not fired? Are you sure your `id`s are unique within the document? I mean the selectors like `.modal-body #fileXXXX` doesn't make sense. Just use `#fileXXXX`.

Comment: I threw an alert in the script and it never popped up. Additionally, the field is not populating.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure what the point of your code is, as you don't actually do anything with the val? But try this:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$('.open-renameFile').click(function () {
    console.log('Event fired!');
    var fileName = $(this).data('name');
    $(".modal-body #fileName").val( fileName );
    var fileId = $(this).data('id');
    $(".modal-body #fileId").val( fileId );
});     
</script>
```

Comment: It still didn't work. Also, I use the values in my Post, I need them on the server side for database updates.

Comment: Did the string get printed to console?

Comment: No, nothing was printed to console.